# How to create a method that can accept arraylist/collection of object - custom class type in actionscript

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, actionscript

Like java, I want to create a method that accepts an array list of particular object type.

In java:

```
public void addStudents(List<Student> students) {
...
}
```

In actionscript

```
public function addStudents(students:ArrayCollection):void {
.....
}
```

Here I want to have public function addStudents(students:ArrayCollection).

Thanks

Comment: Uh, and where is the problem? Is something wrong with mx.collections.ArrayCollection?

Comment: If I do this, some one can pass some other object array as well.

Comment: it will fail later on but I want to stop them and ask explicitly  to pass an array of student type objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a Student object and publish for FP10 you can use the Vector object.

```
public function addStudents(students:Vector.<Student>):void {}
```

For further information: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/Vector.html

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know, AS has no template-like generics. But you can extend ArrayCollection into something like StudentArrayCollection with more rigid type check inside.